# How to set a background image in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt5, background-image, qwebengineview

I'm using QWebEngineView from QtWebEngineWidgets to display an image and I want to make it as a background image. But it does not show anything. How can I do that?

I also try QWebView from QtWebKitWidgets but it still does not work.

Here's my code:

```
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    html = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body{background-image:url("D:\\house.jpg");}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>"""

    view.setHtml(html)
```

I expect the view to display the image house.jpg as the background, but it just displays a white window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QWebEnginePage::setHtml(const QString &html, const QUrl &baseUrl = QUrl())
>
> Sets the content of this page to html. baseUrl is optional and used to resolve
> relative URLs in the document, such as referenced images or stylesheets.

Tested on Windows.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QDateTime, QUrl

html = """
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>background-image</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url('file:///D:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Image/logo.png');
        background-color: #c7b39b;               
      }
      p {
        color: #f00;
        font: bold italic 20pt 'Comic Sans MS';
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

def append():
    some_html = "<p>{}</p>".format(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())
    page.runJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML += '{}'".format(some_html)
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QWebEngineView()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(append)
    page = view.page()
    page.loadFinished.connect(lambda: timer.start(1000))

    page.setHtml(html, baseUrl=QUrl('file://'))                   # <---

    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `baseUrl`:

```
view.setHtml(html, baseUrl='file://')
```

otherwise, it doesn't guess what to do with a `D:\\...` address. 
Tested on linux, it's enough to solve the issue.

Also be careful that under windows, the `\\` will be interpreted. Write `html = r""" ... """` for safety, and save it to a file.html for verifications.